# logstash multiline log for a mysql query

Tags: logstash

I'm looking to push logs from mysql-proxy lua's script into lostash. An example log might be

```
[2015-03-09 11:13:47] USER:username IP:10.102.51.134:41420 DB:dbName Query: -- One Pager Trends 
-- params:

SELECT 
  date,
  SUM(t.rev) revenue,
  SUM(t.rev - t.cost) profit 
FROM
  am.s_d t
  INNER JOIN am.event e 
    ON t.`event_id` = e.`event_id`
WHERE 1=1 AND DATE BETWEEN '2014-12-08' AND '2015-03-08'
  AND t.source_id = 25
GROUP BY date
[2015-03-09 11:17:28] USER:mzupan IP:10.102.22.216:49843 DB: Query: show databases
```

A new log entry will always start with `[`

So i'm shipping the logs using logstash-forwarder and processing like

```
filter {

  if [type] == "mysql-proxy" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}\] USER:%{WORD:user} IP:%{IP:ip}:%{INT} DB:%{DATA:db} Query: (?<query>(.|\r|\n)*)" }
    }
    multiline {
      pattern => "^\["
      what => "previous"
      negate=> true
    }
    date {
      match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
}
```

My issue is in kibana I see the query like the following json

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2015.03.09",
  "_type": "mysql-proxy",
  "_id": "AUv_vj3u0BuDzneUoKKc",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "[2015-03-09 11:13:47] USER:username IP:10.102.51.134:41420 DB:dbName Query: -- One Pager Trends \n-- params:\n\nSELECT \n  date,\n  SUM(t.rev) revenue,\n  SUM(t.rev - t.cost) profit \nFROM\n  am.s_d t\n  INNER JOIN am.event e \n    ON t.`event_id` = e.`event_id`\nWHERE 1=1 AND DATE BETWEEN '2014-12-08' AND '2015-03-08'\n  AND t.source_id = 25\nGROUP BY date",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2015-03-09T18:13:52.287Z",
    "type": "mysql-proxy",
    "file": "/var/log/mysql-queries.log",
    "host": "an01.domain.com",
    "offset": [
      "11855847",
      "11855943",
      "11855954",
      "11855955",
      "11855963",
      "11855971",
      "11855993",
      "11856023",
      "11856028",
      "11856039",
      "11856064",
      "11856099",
      "11856156",
      "11856179",
      "11856193",
      "11856194"
    ],
    "user": "username",
    "ip": "10.102.51.134",
    "db": "dbname",
    "query": "-- One Pager Trends ",
    "tags": [
      "_grokparsefailure",
      "multiline"
    ]
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1425924832287
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1425924832287
  ]
}
```

I'm only seeing the first part even though logstash seems to be setting the message correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiline in your filter should be placed before the match part. Try configuring it like this:

```
filter {
  if [type] == "mysql-proxy" {
    multiline {
      pattern => "^\["
      what    => "previous"
      negate  => true
    }
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}\] USER:%{WORD:user} IP:%{IP:ip}:%{INT} DB:%{DATA:db} Query: (?(.|\r|\n)*)" }
    }
    date {
      match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
```

This works for me with logstash v1.4.2.